# XAMPP not starting (not a port issue)

Tags: xampp

I'm running XAMPP v3.2.1 on Windows 8 and after it was installed it was working fine but then the next day the apache and MySQL are not starting.

I have changed the default port 80 to 8081 in httpd.conf and changed the port 443 to 444 in httpd-ssl.conf but still nothing,

Here's what I am getting in the logs:

Apache error.log:

```
[Thu Jul 30 13:08:06.006405 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1892:tid 400] AH01909: www.example.com:444:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 30 13:08:06.084534 2015] [core:warn] [pid 1892:tid 400] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Jul 30 13:08:06.084534 2015] [core:error] [pid 1892:tid 400] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : AH00099: could not create D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid
[Thu Jul 30 13:08:06.084534 2015] [core:error] [pid 1892:tid 400] AH00100: httpd.exe: could not log pid to file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid
```

MySql mysql_error:

```
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-07-30 13:08:05 17f4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665234 and 1665234 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2075306 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-07-30 13:08:05 8408 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.25 started; log sequence number 2075306
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2015-07-30 13:08:06 8408 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I am still trying to google to find answers but so far all of the answers I  can find suggest that the port is the issue while in this case it isnt

Comment: Checked with `task manager` to ensure they are not running? Are you having them start automatically as services.? It may be worthwhile removing the services and starting them as processes. Make sure they are stopped, by checking with `task manager` then delete a the log files from the  `apache/logs` directory. What messages do you get when just starting `apache`?

Comment: @RyanVincent Yep and I even restarted my computer to make sure that nothing is running but xampp, and yeah I have them to start automatically once I open xampp, but I have to open xampp it doesn't open on its own on windows load.
Sorry but what do you mean by `It may be worthwhile removing the services and starting them as processes.`

Comment: maybe useful? [How To Troubleshoot XAMPP Apache Not Running on Windows 7](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-troubleshoot-xampp-apache-not-running-on-windows-7). Also, [
Apache Friends Support Forum](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=162462). It is very similar on Windows 8

Comment: @RyanVincent nope both mention that the issue is in the port, in my case the problem is not that a port is taken.